# What is Dovecot namespace inbox for?

Tags: dovecot

Settings for dovecot is interesting.
But there are a few things that i am not aware of.

What is the namespace inbox?
What is it for?

In *10-mail.conf* we can define the namespace inbox, and if its defined we can set it up in detail in *15-mailboxes.conf*.

In my case, the pop3 works correctly without defining inbox namespace.
So when to use inbox?
Also we are using maildir instead of mbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single `namespace inbox` is the default namespace that exists even if no namespaces are declared. This is the namespace containing your maildirs. You can also declare another namespace say `MyOld` for old `mailbox` migrated from old server as huge single file. Then you can see that namespace among the `Inbox`, `Sent`, `Trash` and can access it. The default namespace will be in maildir++ format while `MyOld` namespace will be in `mailbox` format.

There is few other purposes namespaces are suitable for like shared or public mailboxes. You can read https://wiki.dovecot.org/Namespaces for further information.

For example this is the config that allows to merge the `mbox` formatted dump of the gmail mailbox to the maildir mailbox:

```
namespace main {
  location      = maildir:/data/mail/%d/%n:UTF-8
  prefix        =
  type          = private
  order         = 0
  disabled      = no
  hidden        = no
  inbox         = yes
  subscriptions = yes
  list          = yes
  separator     = .
}

namespace gmail {
  location      = mbox:/data/mail/%d/%n/GMAIL
  prefix        = "GMail."
  type          = private
  inbox         = no
  list          = yes
  hidden        = yes
  separator     = .
}
```

Then you have to drop the dumpfile into the /data/mail/%d/%n/GMAIL and voila - all your google mail is here.